# How can I use Nginx server blocks and Django?

Tags: django, nginx, server, block

I'm following the guide from this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) However, when I link my `home.html` file in my django app's template folder, it doesn't load the css files and it doesn't understand any of the "`{% %}`" syntax.

How can I configure my nginx server block to load my django app properly?

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myonlinefp.com` file:

```
server {

    root /home/stelity/myonlinefp/foodpantry/templates/;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html home.html;

    server_name myonlinefp.com www.myonlinefp.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /media {
        alias /home/stelity/myonlinefp/foodpantry/media/;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myonlinefp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by
    Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myonlinefp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {

    if ($host = www.myonlinefp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        if ($host = myonlinefp.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            } # managed by Certbot


            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            server_name myonlinefp.com www.myonlinefp.com;
}
```

Updated, this is the edited file for a reply below:

> server {
>
> ```
> root unix:://run/gunicorn.sock;
>
> server_name myonlinefp.com www.myonlinefp.com;
>
> location / {
>     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
> }
> location /media {
>     alias /home/stelity/myonlinefp/foodpantry/media/;
> }
>
> listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
> listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
> ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myonlinefp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by
> ```
>
> Certbot
> ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myonlinefp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
> include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
> ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot }
>
> server {
>
> ```
> if ($host = www.myonlinefp.com) {
>     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
>     } # managed by Certbot
>
>
>     if ($host = myonlinefp.com) {
>         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
>         } # managed by Certbot
>
>
>         listen 80;
>         listen [::]:80;
>
>         server_name myonlinefp.com www.myonlinefp.com; }
> ```

Comment: Does your application working properly in your local machine because I think Django not rendering your template properly this may happen because of invalid syntax

Comment: It works properly on local machine. It works on nginx as well, but once I installed server block for nginx, I don't know how to configure the server block to go to my app. Right now, it's pointed to my home.html page in my templates folder and it opens exactly that file and doesn't understand syntax that django does.

Comment: Check whether your service(gunicorn) is running or not

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly fine. It works perfectly fine for http://159.223.177.51/ but it doesn't work when I use the domain name because the server block is pointed to open the .html file and just the .html file without using django.

Comment: Did you created sock file for your service ? if yes then inside your `server{}` block set `root` to `path/to/sockfile` and remove `index` becouse you don't need that else evrything is fine I think

Comment: Thanks, when I change "root" section to "unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;", it gives me a 404 error :/

Comment: you're getting 404 while accessing page or in status of nginx ? check whether your `gunicorn.sock` is in `/run/` directory

Comment: Add updated nginx configuration in your question by making an [edit]

Comment: Looks a bit sloppy, but I edited the first post to include the updated code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You've added wrong `unix:://run/gunicorn.sock;` path it should be `http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;`

Comment: I still get a 404 error. It loads when I add it to the location: location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    } . It loads the media files, but not the static and it doesn't work with crsf token

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated ***nginx*** configuration

```
server {

    root unix:://run/gunicorn.sock;
    server_name myonlinefp.com www.myonlinefp.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /home/stelity/myonlinefp/foodpantry/media/;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/stelity/myonlinefp/foodpantry;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myonlinefp.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myonlinefp.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {

    if ($host = www.myonlinefp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = myonlinefp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name myonlinefp.com www.myonlinefp.com;
}
```

after adding this you've to run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

command & make sure you've configured your static files in ***`settings.py`*** like this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = ['/path/to/static/dir/']

STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/static_root/dir/'
```

an make sure your ***`STATIC_ROOT`*** must be same as your nginx location name. For more information you can check [**Serving Static Content**](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)

Comment: That didn't work, but adding the location worked: location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

Comment: But it didn't solved your static issue when you navigate to admin your static content will not serve to serve static files you've to configure your nginx so check static part in nginx configuration

Comment: well, going to myonlinefp.com/admin doesn't load static, but the static files work in myonlinefp.com. I can see my custom fonts. My media files work too. I tried your solution, but it gave me a 404 error.

Comment: Hello @stelity 404 where it'sgiving you did you run collectstatic and `STATICFILES_DIR`, `STATIC_ROOT` should be your path and all other stuf is same as your nginx conf. I've just added static part check i've edited my answer little bit